# Retrieve JSON data with string variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, jira-plugin

I'm developing custom field plugin for Jira Cloud in React.

I have a variable `cfDate1` which is stores custom field id as a string like `customfield_10072`.

So I want to reach the time data inside my custom field id.

Let's say my data is in `jsonData` variable.
I try to reach with `jsonData.fields.[cfDate1]` but I get `Error: Identifier expected.`

I searched a few but I think I couldn't find the right keywords to get some solutions.
Is there anyone can help me to figure it out. I need to learn how to reach json data in my json query with a string variable. Thanks already!

JSON Format (`jsonData`):

```
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations,customfield_10010.requestTypePractice",
  "id": "10008",
  "self": "https://alimert.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/10008",
  "key": "SP-1",
  "fields": {
    "statuscategorychangedate": "2021-10-11T12:17:41.291+0300",
    "customfield_10072": "2021-01-13T02:00:00.000+0300",
    "customfield_10073": "2021-01-26T06:30:00.000+0300",
    "customfield_10075": "2021-10-14",
    "customfield_10076": "2021-10-15" }
```

Comment: Maybe `jsonData.fields[cfDate1]` (without the fullstop)?

Comment: Please also note that once JSON is parsed, it is no-longer JSON.

Comment: there are two ways to access the field value:- 
1) jsonData.fields[cfDate1]   -> if cfDate1 is a variable, or jsonData.fields["customfield_10072"] -> for specific field name.   2) jsonData.fields.cfDate1 -> here cfDate1 is the keyName not a variable

Comment: @DebasisRath actually there are four, there is also `x?.y` and `x?.[y]`, and with the latter having both `.` and `[]` it is reasonable to be confused.

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT, that come under optional chaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It has to be `jsonData.fields[cfDate1]` and not `jsonData.fields.[cfDate1]`.**

---

There are four ways to access a property of an object<sup>1</sup>:

| Syntax | Dynamic key | Optional chaining | `.` | `[]` | `?` | Equivalents<sup>2</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `obj.xyz` | No | No | Yes | No | No | `obj['xyz']` |
| `obj[key]` | Yes | No | No | Yes | No | - |
| `obj?.xyz` | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes | `obj == null ? obj.xyz : undefined` `obj == null ? obj['xyz'] : undefined` |
| `obj?.[key]` ⚠️ | Yes | Yes | Yes ⚠️ | Yes | Yes | `obj == null ? obj[key] : undefined` |

As you can see in this table, in most cases you use ***either* `.` (for static keys) *or* `[]` (for dynamic keys)**.

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) adds a `?`. However, in the case of optional chaining *and* a dynamic key, the possibly unexpected syntax of `?.[]` is used which has *both* `.` and `[]`<sup>3</sup>. Note that this is *only* the case with optional chaining - **without optional chaining, the syntax `.[]` is *not* valid**.

---

<sub>**1:** There is also `Reflect.get(obj, key)`, and you could stretch that definition to count something involving walking the prototype chain, calling `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and accessing `value` or `get` as well, if you really wanted to. But for a beginner, these would be, if anything, more of academic interest and rather confusing to include in a list of property access methods for everyday use.</sub>

<sub>**2:** For optional chaining, the shown equivalents only apply to the case of no further level of chaining (e.g. `obj?.xyz` but not `obj?.xyz.abc`). An additional - quite useful - property of the optional chaining operator is that it stops evaluation of the rest of the expression entirely in case the left-hand side is nullish, so that you can write `obj?.xyz.abc` instead of `obj?.xyz?.abc` without an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "abc")`. With the shown equivalent that wouldn't work.</sub>

<sub>**3:** The reason for this slightly awkward syntax is that optional chaining was added to the language only recently, and `?[]` couldn't have been used due to ambiguity with the ternary operator and added difficulty in writing parsers to handle this situation. The same goes for `?.()`. See [FAQ in the optional chaining proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining#faq) for more information.</sub>